# Why can't my my modified copy of the docker elasticsearch be accessed from a browser?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, dockerfile

I am attempting to run a customized image based on the official Elasticsearch image from Docker. However, when I try to access it through `localhost:9200`, it does not work.

I created a custom-elasticsearch.yml file with host set to 127.0.0.1 (localhost), then build an elasticsearch-custom image and ran it. Steps can be found in the link below.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/docker.html

When I try to access the elasticsearch through a browser at `localhost:9200`, it fails to connect. How do I repair this?

Code in Dockerfile for elasticsearch-custom

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.3
COPY --chown=elasticsearch:elasticsearch elasticsearch.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/
```

Building the custom docker

```
docker build --tag=elasticsearch-custom .
```

Method to run elasticsearch-custom

```
docker run -d -ti -v /usr/share/elasticsearch/data -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch-custom
```

When I type `localhost:9200` into the browser, I expect it to return the data from the elasticsearch.

But instead the browser says it is unable to connect.

Comment: When you say "host set to 127.0.0.1", what did you change exactly?  (In general if a Docker container binds to 127.0.0.1 it will be unreachable from outside the container, and you need to set the bind address to 0.0.0.0, which is usually the default.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following parameter to Docker run command, so your container and the host os will share the same network interface. Then you should be able to access Docker container with localhost:9200

`--network=host`

The final run command should be like this;

`docker run -d -ti -v /usr/share/elasticsearch/data --network=host -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch-custom`

Comment: Modified command still did not work.

It printed out: WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode

And when I tried to open localhost:9200, the browser did not connect to the elasticsearch.